# Why does my Gridsearch on Keras NN - Model just loop?

Tags: keras

i have a problem with gridsearch keras problem which loops every time with the same epoch = 25? It doesn't change to 35.

```
def build_classifier(optimizer):
    classifier = Sequential()
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 3000, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = pca_dimensions))
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 3000, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
    classifier.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    return classifier

classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn = build_classifier)

parameters = {'batch_size': [1000],
              'epochs': [25,35,45],
              'optimizer': ['adam']}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = classifier,
                           param_grid = parameters,
                           scoring = 'accuracy',
                           cv = 10)enter code here
grid_results = grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_results.best_score_, grid_results.best_params_))
means = grid_results.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_results.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_results.cv_results_['params']
for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))
```

Comment: Maybe you're seeing 10 `cv` loops first, then you will see another 10 cv loops for another group of parameters? Try to have less `cv` to check.

Comment: thanks i will check it!